# External pole Lighting help

Tags: wiring

Planning to run 6 lights from a sub panel around my pool. 20 Amp GFI breaker in-place. Planning to run THWN 12 gauge wire in plastic conduit for the lights (pole lights) with at least 2 switches. Want to add an outlet at base of each pole for added electrical options (low amp/watt) decorative rope lights or Christmas lights. 
Unsure of how to add the receptacles. Also, may want to have a separate switch for the receptacles. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: DO the poles have any provision for a receptacle?  Many do...

Comment: This seems like a pretty basic wiring scenario, so I'm unsure what you question is.  What specifically are you having an issue with?

Comment: What make and model are the poles you are looking at, or have you not picked your poles out yet?

Comment: I have the poles. Got them at a restore. There is no receptacle on them. I would need to probably mount the recpticles close to the pokes. Currently the poles have concrete on them with conduit for woofing. I don’t want to remove the concrete so will just just bury them with additional fresh concrete.